# Running asp.NET application on a local computer for testing purposes

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, web

I developed a web application for some small company. It connects to an SQL database created in Microsoft SQL server Managment studio 2008. Now they would like to test this app on a local computer before they put it on a server.

My question is, what are all the things I need to make this app work on a random computer running Win with no Visual Studio or SQL server installed?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: They want to run it on a local computer only.

Comment: It sounds like you already know... what OS are they on?

Comment: win 7 on that particular computer

Comment: Personally, I would assemble a self-containing VMware image and ship this one to the customer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 can help you out. 
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: This program worked great. So much easier to install all the things you need. :) Thnx

Answer (score 2):

- Install .Net version you are using.  It might already be there.
- Install/configure IIS
- Install SQL Server Express
- Your db connection string obviously need to be changed to the local
  sql server connection in web.config
- Because it is a simple app, just copy the entire app (except proj
  files, .cs, .vb files) to that computer

Comment: I was thinking something like this. What about the actual application...how do I set the connection to the database? Do I need to change the path before I publish it in VS?

Answer (score 1):

For one, point the connection string at SQL Server on a staging server. The whole idea of testing is to have the same environment as the production server.